# How to implement compile time product of two vectors in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, compile-time

The scalar product of two vectors with size 'N' defined as SP(a, b) = a_1 * b_1 + ... + a_N * b_N.

Compile-time integer vector defined as:

```
template<int... I>
struct Vector;
```

Function product interface:

```
template<typename Vector1, typename Vector2>
constexpr int product
```

For example, following code could be used for test:

```
static_assert(product<Vector<1, 2, 5>, Vector<1, 3, 4>> == 27);
```

How can product be implemented to match the assert and interface above?

Comment: Have you at all tried to implement anything?

Comment: try recursion. Lets say you already know how to compute the scalar product of `Vector<x,...>` and `Vector<y,...>` then what is the scalar product of `Vector<a,x,...>` and `Vector<b,y,...>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
template<int ... >
struct Vector{};

template<int ... Idx1, int ... Idx2>
constexpr int product(Vector<Idx1...>, Vector<Idx2...>) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Idx1) == sizeof...(Idx2), "Product cannot be calculated, dims dismatched");
    int res = 0;
    int temp [] = { (res +=  (Idx1 * Idx2),0)...};
    static_cast<void>(temp);
    return res;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(product(Vector<1,2,5>{},Vector<1,3,4>{}) == 27);
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xZRx_y)

Comment: If you can use C++17, `product()` can simply `return (... + (Idx1 * Idx2));`; if you can't use C++17, you have to add the second argument in `static_assert()`.

Comment: `static_cast<void>(temp);` is the fancy way to suppress a unused warning?

Comment: @max66 I cannot figure out why I should add second argument to static_assert? What is the reason of that?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, it eliminates warnings.

Comment: @rafix - because only starting from C++17 `static_assert()` accept only one argument; before C++17 (C++11 and C++14) require also the second (the error message) argument.

Comment: @rafix07 - you're welcome :-). IMHO you should valorize your answer signaling that your solution works also with C++11 and C++14 (well... in C++11 `product()` can't be `constexpr`).

Answer (score 5):

With C++17 folding

```
template <int...>
struct Vector
 { };

template <typename, typename>
constexpr int product = -1;

template <int ... Is, int ... Js>
constexpr int product<Vector<Is...>, Vector<Js...>> = (... + (Is*Js));

int main ()
 {
   static_assert(product<Vector<1, 2, 5>, Vector<1, 3, 4>> == 27);
 }
```

Comment: Rather than `-1`, I'd omit a value in the base template

Comment: @Caleth - omitting it, I get a compilation error ("error: default initialization of an object of const type 'const int'")

Comment: [I don't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a2916fbaad8e52b)

Comment: @Caleth - I'm using (also) clang++ (`-Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=c++17 -I. -stdlib=libc++`)

Comment: @Caleth - adding something as `std::cout << product<int, int> << std::endl;` in `main()`, you should obtain a compilation error also with g++

Comment: `product<int, int>` *doesn't exist*, so it's correct to be a compile error

Comment: @Caleth - Uhmmm... if you say thay `product<int, int>` isn't desired, according the OP question, I'm agree and the g++ compilation error only using it is good; unfortunately clang++ gives the compilation error also if you don't use `product<int, int>`. But if you say that `product<int, int>` doesn't exist *tout court*, I disagree: if you initialize the not specialized version of `product` (as in my answer), you can compile, without errors, also `std::cout << product<int, int> << std::endl;` with both compilers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209467/discussion-between-caleth-and-max66).

Answer (score 0):

Without C++17 fold expressions, by using function overloading.

```
template <int... Ele>
struct vector {};

template <int Ele1, int Ele2>
constexpr int DotProd(vector<Ele1> v1, vector<Ele2> v2) {
    return Ele1 * Ele2;
}

template <int Ele1First, int... Ele1, int Ele2First, int... Ele2>
constexpr int DotProd (vector<Ele1First, Ele1...> v1, vector<Ele2First, Ele2...> v2) {
    return (Ele1First * Ele2First) + DotProd(vector<Ele1...>{}, vector<Ele2...> {});
}

int main() {
   
    vector<1, 2, 3, 4> v1;
    vector<4, 3, 2, 1> v2;

    static_assert (DotProd(v1, v2) == 20);
    return 0;
}
```